# Why is text wrapping around a floating element instead of going belows like another div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand CSS a bit deeper and I noticed that when a `div` is floating other elements go beneath it. That is not the case for text that wraps arount it. How come ?

Comment: Other divs don't go below a floating div either. The determining factor is if whatever content is narrow enough to fit next to the floating div, otherwise it is forced down. It doesn't matter if it's text or an image or anything.

Comment: @MrLister I don't agree, other divs will go *below* and by below we don't mean a new line but below it considering the z-axis because div (block element) will not wrap around float element https://jsfiddle.net/3e8ojmcw/

Comment: Good point. So ​​@​​W​​i​​c​​e​​l​​o​​, did you mean beneath as lower on the screen or behind as deeper in the stack?

Comment: Mr. Lister your first comment is incorrect. Simply adding text to a div that only has padding changes it from being concealed by a floating element to being pushed below it (and becoming fully visible). Try adding text to the div with a class "second" in this CodePen. https://codepen.io/x-x00102/pen/OJWazBw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design as this is how float works. If you refer to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):

> The float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, allowing **text and inline elements to wrap around it**. The element is **removed from the normal flow** of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow.

You should note 2 features of float elements:

- Removed from normal flow: Which means that others elements can overlap floating element or be overlaped by floating element (like with `position:absolute`)
- text and inline elements will wrap around: Only text and inline level elements will not be overlap floating element but will wrap around it.

Here is some basic examples to better understand:

```css
.float {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.blue {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

The blue div is overlaped by the float element because it's a block level element.

It won't be the case if we make it an inline level element (`inline-block`)

```css
.float {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.blue {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

---

When we add text you will notice how the text will wrap around the float element and will be kept inside it's containing block (the blue div).

```css
.float {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.blue {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color:#fff;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="blue">  some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here</div>
```

The same happen if we have more of the blue divs:

```css
.float {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.blue {
  width: 200px;
  color:#fff;
  background: blue;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="blue">  some text here some text here s</div>

<div class="blue">  some text here some text here some</div>
```

To make it easy: a float element will overlap all the block element around it and inline element will wrap around it.

Comment: Well when you set the blue element to `inline` (you set it to `inline-block`) it is hidden under the red floating div, that's my question basically, because text is `inline `not `inline-block`

Comment: @Wicelo inline and inline-block are the same, they both will wrap around float .. i simply used inline-block to be able to add height/width because with inline element we cannot set width/height but both are "inline level element"

Comment: @Wicelo so if you set inline to the blue div, you will simply not see it if there is no content inside it

Comment: you are right the inline display shrunk the div (i had &nbsp; in it) and I thought it was going under but it was just shrunk.

Comment: @Wicelo add some content on it and you will see https://jsfiddle.net/m2ydjqp8/ ... the width/height is defined by content and the use of width/height will have no effect because this is how inline element work but notice how it wrap around unlike a block element and exactly like inline-block element