# div float property explanation

Tags: css, css-float

According to [www1](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):
"The `float` property can have one of the following values:
`left` - The element floats to the left of its `container`"
and also "In HTML, the container is the area enclosed by the beginning and ending tags. "([www2](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/container.html))

In the following code (code in [1](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)):

```
.div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<body>
<h2>Without clear</h2>
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2 - Notice that div2 is after div1 in the HTML code. However, since div1 floats to the left, the text in div2 flows around div1.</div>
</body>
```

Questions are:

1. Is body element the container of `div1`?
2. If it is, `div1` float to the
   left. And I guess it ends the function of float. Why does the text
   in `div2` flow around `div1`?

Comment: this will probably help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457727/why-is-text-wrapping-around-a-floating-element-instead-of-going-belows-like-anot/53461888#53461888

Comment: This one also help: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PxMqXe?&editable=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your example, *my* answers to your questions:

1. Yes
2. Think about *all* of the properties you're assigning to the **div1** class - you've assigned a margin (thus displacing the text within **div2**), and are 'floating' that div to the left. 
   **div** tags don't natively have **float:** properties - in the absence of one, it behaves natively - keeping its position, taking up the full width of its container.

The screenshot below is meant to visualize what I'm trying to say above in #2

[image]

Oh, and the **float:** CSS directive isn't a *function* - but a style applied to an element on the visible DOM.
Personally and depending on what I'm trying to accomplish, I almost never use **float** in production if I can help it.

Comment: Did you mean that div in "and are 'floating' that div to the left. "  div2 or div1?

Comment: div1 looks to me like the only class assigned the 'float:' property. There is no float property assigned to div2 - it behaves like a div should

Comment: div1 floats to the left of body container. And that is over. Then why does div2 seem floating on top of div1?

Comment: In short? Because div2 has no float - the 'float' property is not a native property of a div, and therefore the div acts as it otherwise would. It's the float property that's changing this natural instinct of div1. div2 didn't get invited to the float party, so while she's jealous of div1's additional CSS properties, she isn't going to compromise her natural instincts and behave irrationally